# Terraform helm release timing out problem

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy `helm_release` using terraform script. My `.tf` file looks like below

```
resource "helm_release" "ingress-aws" {
  name       = "ingress-aws"
  repository = "https://aws.github.io/eks-charts"
  chart      = "aws-load-balancer-controller"
  version    = "2.1.3"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.aws-ingress-controller.metadata[0].name
  #namespace = "ingress-aws"
  atomic     = true
  timeout    = 300
  values = [<<EOF
clusterName: dcp-daas-test14-dcp-eks
serviceAccount:
  name: aws-load-balancer
```

when i run my deployment pipeline, after reaching at this stage it waits for 5 minutes (as timeout=300 sec) and then gives out an error saying something like this:

```
Error: [0m[0m[1mrelease ingress-aws failed, and has been uninstalled due to atomic being set: timed out waiting for the condition

on ingress.tf line 64, in resource "helm_release" "ingress-aws":
64: resource "helm_release" "ingress-aws" [4m{[0m
```

i tried changing the version of the helm release and tried applying this `helm_release` on newly created EKS cluster yet the same issue.

Any advice would be appreciated and ask question in comments if you want more info about the question.

Also I tried installing helm release chart version V-1.1.6 and it works fine but when i go with the V-1.2.2 it gives me above error. Not sure if it is causing due to any bugs in latest version of helm chart !!

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: What errors are you seeing on the kubernetes side? What's the status of the pods, are there any events, have you looked at the container logs?